# Select variables out of a list which consist out of 3 different variables with index numbers

Tags: python

My model consists out of 3 variables: X(j), I(j) AND S(j), where j is a different day. X=amount of products produced,
I= amount of products in inventory,
S= amount of sales of the product.

After running the model with an objective function and some constrains, i receive a long output of:

```
x[0] 0
x[1] 3
x[2] 3
x[3] 8
x[4] 7
x[5] 5
```

etc..

With the following function i put the results in a list named solutions:

```
solutions = []

for v in m.getVars():
    solutions.append([v.varName, v.x])
    print("%s %g" % (v.varName, v.x))

print(solutions)
```

The following list is the output:

```
[['x[0]', 0.0], ['x[1]', 3.0], ['x[2]', 3.0], ['x[3]', 8.0], ['x[4]', 7.0], ['x[5]', 5.0], ['x[6 etc......
```

My question is, How can I put X, I and S in different lists with their corresponding values?

I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: Where do the `I` and `S` values come from? This only seems to generate `X` values.

Comment: Please provide a [MRE].

Comment: @Barmar After ['x[52], 9,0], ['S[0]', 2,0], ['S[1], 3.0]... etc is shown. After S[52], the same happens with I.

Answer (score -1):

Check the first character of `v.varname` to determine which list to append to.

```
x_solutions = []
s_solutions = []
i_solutions = []

for v in m.getVars():
    if v.varName.startswith('x['):
        solutions = x_solutions
    elif v.varName.startswith('I['):
        solutions = i_solutions
    elif v.varName.startswith('S['):
        solutions = s_solutions
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid variable {v.varName}")

    solutions.append([v.varName, v.x])
    print("%s %g" % (v.varName, v.x))
```